# Exception with lambda express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, exception, lambda

I have a strange behavior. The code below worked from a long time but nowI don't know why I didn't change anything, I have an exception. I get employee from my database via Nhibernate, the _model.List have the employee list. I have an exception on the line juste before the return (where I build the array). I format the data to use them in jqGrid.

The exception is : *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ListToGrid(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    _model.List = _employeeService.List();

    Func<Employee, string> order;
    switch (sidx.ToUpper())
    {
        case "FIRSTNAME": order = x => x.FirstName; break;
        case "LASTNAME": order = x => x.LastName; break;
        default: order = x => x.Login; break;
    }

    if (sord.ToUpper() == "ASC")
        _model.List = _model.List.OrderBy(order).ToList<Employee>();
    else
        _model.List = _model.List.OrderByDescending(order).ToList<Employee>();

    var data = _model.List.Select(c => new { id = c.Id, cell = new[] { c.Id.ToString(), c.Login.ToString(), c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.IsActive.ToString() } }).ToArray();
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { page = page, records = data.Length, rows = data, total = 1 } };            
}
```

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: @Adam Robinson: "I have an exception on the line juste before the return (where I build the array)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're saying that this line

```
var data = _model.List.Select(c => new { id = c.Id, cell = new[] { 
    c.Id.ToString(),
    c.Login.ToString(),
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName,
    c.IsActive.ToString()
} }).ToArray();
```

throws an exception. Then, it would appear quite likely either `c.Id`, `c.Login` or `c.IsActive` is null for at least one `c` in `_model.List` as these are the only properties of `c` for which a dereference is necessary. Those are your main culprits so start checking your data.

Comment: .Where(c => c != null).Select()

Comment: Well, the straightforward approach is to, say, replace `c.Id.ToString()` by `c.Id == null ? String.Empty : c.Id.ToString()` and repeat for each of the possibly-null properties. Of course, you can consider factoring this logic into a method.

Comment: @dittodhole: No, that eliminates the `c` where `c` is null and doesn't deal at all with the `c` where `c.Id` or `c.Login` or `c.IsActive` is `null`. Moreover, the OP doesn't want to filter those `c` out as he permits the possibility of them being `null`.

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, you have a row in your database with Id, Login or IsActive set to null.  Can you post the entire stacktrace for more info?